# Laravel/Vite/Inertiajs doesn't seem to be able to import pages from a sub directory (in my pages folder)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vite, inertiajs

When i just place my `Register`  page in the pages folder like this:

```
/pages
   - Register.vue
```

Then everything works normally and the page loads, but when i place my `Register` page in the `auth` folder like this:

```
/pages
   /auth
      - Register.vue
```

It doesn't work, this is the error that i see when i open the console:

```
dynamic-import-helper:7 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown variable dynamic import: ./pages/auth/Register.vue
    at dynamic-import-helper:7:96
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at default (dynamic-import-helper:6:12)
    at resolve (app.js:5:22)
    at e2.h2 [as resolveComponent] (createInertiaApp.js:8:52)
    at n2.setPage (router.ts:378:33)
    at router.ts:323:19
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

This is my vite.config.js code:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

This is my app.js code:

```
import {createApp, h} from 'vue';
import {createInertiaApp} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: name => import(`./pages/${name}.vue`),
    setup({el, app, props, plugin}) {
        createApp({render: () => h(app, props)})
            .use(plugin)
            .mount(el)
    }
});
```

I have tried changing the `${name}`  to just auth/Register and then it just works? But thats not a real solution ofc.

This is the method i call tho render the `Register` page:

```
public function register(): Response|ResponseFactory
{
    return Inertia::render('auth/Register');
}
```

Comment: u changed it all to lowercase on purpose? `./pages/${name}.vue` should be `./Pages/${name}.vue`

Comment: @ericmp yes i dit change ´pages´ on purpose to lawercase, i just changed it back but that didn't fix the problem sadly.

Comment: yeah but u probably also changed more stuff i guess. if is a new project, u can just start from 0 and not change unnecessary stuff

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by rewriting it following the [Inertia's doc](https://inertiajs.com/client-side-setup).

I'm on `@inertiajs/react": "^1.0.2"` and my code looks like this:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/react';

const createApp = () =>
  createInertiaApp({
    resolve: (name) => {
      const pages = import.meta.glob('./pages/**/*.tsx', { eager: true });
      const page = pages[`./pages/${name}.tsx`];
      return page;
    },
    setup({ el, App, props }) {
      createRoot(el).render(<App {...props} />);
    },
  });

export default createApp;
```

the `import.meta.glob` is a [vite's built-in feature](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import) which would pre-build all the components found in this glob pattern and will store them in an array. Then , you then you access the page(module) you need to render from this array and return it in the resolve method.

I hope it helps!